# Removing Unicode from Pandas Column Text

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I am attempting to determine if the data inside a list is within a dataframe column. I am new to Pandas and have been struggling with this, so at the moment I am turning the dataframe column of interest into a list. However, when I df.tolist() the list contains a slew of unicode around the string. As i am attempting to compare this with text from the other list which is not in unicode I am running into issues.

I am attempted to turn the other list into unicode but then the list had items such that read like u'["item"]' which didn't help. I have also tried to remove the unicode from the dataframe but only get errors. I cannot iterate as pandas tells me that the dataframe is to long to iterate over.  Below is my code:

```
SDC_wb = pd.ExcelFile('C:\ BLeh')
df = SDC_wb.parse(SDC_wb.sheet_names[1], header = 1)

def Follower_count(filename):
    filename = open(filename)
    reader = csv.reader(filename)

    handles = df['things'].tolist()

    print handles

    dict1 = {}

    for item in reader:
        if item in handles:
            user = api.get_user(item)
            dict1[item] = user.Follower_count

    newdf = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
    newdf.to_csv('test1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is what the list from the dataframe looks like:

```
 [u'@Mastercard', u'@Visa', u'@AmericanExpress', u'@CapitalOne']
```

Here is what x = [unicode(s) for s in some_list] looks like:

```
u"['@HomeGoods']", u"['@pier1']", u"['@houzz']", u"['@InteriorDesign']", u"['@zulily']"]
```

Naturally these don't align to check the "in" requirement. Thus, I need a method of converting the .tolist() object from:

```
[u'@Mastercard', u'@Visa', u'@AmericanExpress', u'@CapitalOne']
```

to:

```
[@Mastercard, @Visa, @AmericanExpress, @CapitalOne]
```

so that the for item in handles function will see similar handles.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include the error(s) you receive. No one can guess exactly what the problem is (from the code, there appear to be a few) without your file, in this case.

Comment: I guess that you are using python 2 so your easiest solution would be to switch to python 3 (which uses uft8 stings by default, so no u'string' anmore).

Comment: Converting the other list to contain unicode strings is most probably the cleanest thing to do. It looks like you tried `unicode(some_list)`. Try this instead: `x = [unicode(s) for s in some_list]`.

Comment: Show a sample input df, sample output, and desired output. Do not forget mention your Python version.